# Fetch multiple values stored as key-value pairs in the json date type and display as columns

Tags: mysql, json, key-value

I have a database table that stores the sales data and the associated extra charges in a key-value format using the `json` date type. Following is the minimal structure.

```
saleID  amount extra_charges
------- ------ ----------------------------------------------------------
123     1000   [{"key": "Handling Charges", "amount": 20}, {"key": "Packing Charges", "amount": 15}]
345     1500   [{"key": "Transportation Charges", "amount": 10}, {"key": "Packing Charges", "amount": 0}]
567     240    [{"key": "Handling Charges", "amount": 10}, {"key": "Transportation Charges", "amount": 20}, {"key": "Packing Charges", "amount": 15}]
...
```

I would like to display the data in the following format in my dashboard:

```
Sale ID  Amount  Handling Charges   Transportation Charges   Packing Charges
-------  ------  -----------------  -----------------------  ----------------
123      1000    20                 0                        15
345      1500    0                  10                       0
567      240     10                 20                       15
...
```

I have tried using `json_extract` function to fetch the data, but failed.

`json_extract(extra_charges, '$.key')`

How would I write a query for this?

Comment: Once you have parsed the data, build an RDBMS table with the columns.  JSON is clumsy to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `JSON_EXTRACT` recursively to fetch the key from the extra_charges.
This way, I didn't have to create a temp derived table as suggested in the `JSON_TABLE` approach.

Further, this method works in MySQL 5.7 version as well.

```
SELECT
 COALESCE(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(extra_charges, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(JSON_EXTRACT(extra_charges, '$[*].key'), 'one', 'Handling Charges'))), '$.amount'), 0) as 'Handling Charges',
 COALESCE(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(extra_charges, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(JSON_EXTRACT(extra_charges, '$[*].key'), 'one', 'Transportation Charges'))), '$.amount'), 0) as 'Transportation Charges',
 COALESCE(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(extra_charges, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(JSON_EXTRACT(extra_charges, '$[*].key'), 'one', 'Packing Charges'))), '$.amount'), 0) as 'Packing Charges'
FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 1):

It was hard, but I found a solution.

As you cannot change the structure of the data stored, a possible solution could be something like this (replace yourTable with the right name):

```
SELECT 
    yourTable.saleID AS 'Sale ID', 
    yourTable.amount as 'Amount',
    IFNULL(
        JSON_EXTRACT(newJSON, '$.Handling_Charges'), 0
    ) AS 'Handling Charges',

    IFNULL(
        JSON_EXTRACT(newJSON, '$.Packing_Charges'), 0
    ) AS 'Packing Charges',

    IFNULL(
        JSON_EXTRACT(newJSON, '$.Transportation_Charges'), 0
    ) AS 'Transportation Charges'

FROM yourTable, 
(
    SELECT saleID, CONCAT('{', GROUP_CONCAT(jsonText SEPARATOR ','), '}') AS newJSON
    FROM (
        SELECT saleID,
            CONCAT('"', REPLACE(keyVal, ' ', '_'), '"', ': ',
            IF(JSON_EXTRACT(extra_charges, CONCAT('$[0].key')) = keyVal,
                JSON_EXTRACT(
                    extra_charges, 
                    CONCAT('$[0].amount')
                ), 
                IF(JSON_EXTRACT(extra_charges, CONCAT('$[1].key')) = keyVal,
                    JSON_EXTRACT(
                        extra_charges, 
                        CONCAT('$[1].amount')
                    ), 
                    IF(JSON_EXTRACT(extra_charges, CONCAT('$[2].key')) = keyVal,
                        JSON_EXTRACT(
                            extra_charges, 
                            CONCAT('$[2].amount')
                        ), 
                        0
                    )
                )
            )) AS jsonText
        FROM spr_lead
        JOIN ( 
          SELECT 'Handling Charges' AS keyVal UNION
          SELECT 'Transportation Charges' AS keyVal UNION
          SELECT 'Packing Charges' AS keyVal 
        ) AS `keys` 
    ) AS auxTable
    GROUP BY saleID
) AS newJson
WHERE newJson.saleID = yourTable.saleID
```

This query is composed by three nested queries that are explained below:

**The innermost query**

```
SELECT 
    saleID,
    CONCAT('"', REPLACE(keyVal, ' ', '_'), '"', ': ',
        IF(JSON_EXTRACT(extra_charges, CONCAT('$[0].key')) = keyVal,
            JSON_EXTRACT(
                extra_charges, 
                CONCAT('$[0].amount')
            ), 
            IF(JSON_EXTRACT(extra_charges, CONCAT('$[1].key')) = keyVal,
                JSON_EXTRACT(
                    extra_charges, 
                    CONCAT('$[1].amount')
                ), 
                IF(JSON_EXTRACT(extra_charges, CONCAT('$[2].key')) = keyVal,
                    JSON_EXTRACT(
                        extra_charges, 
                        CONCAT('$[2].amount')
                    ), 
                    0
                )
            )
        )) AS jsonText
    FROM spr_lead
    JOIN ( 
      SELECT 'Handling Charges' AS keyVal UNION
      SELECT 'Transportation Charges' AS keyVal UNION
      SELECT 'Packing Charges' AS keyVal 
    ) AS `keys`
) AS auxTable
```

It gets the JSON field and creates a string with structure `"key": value` replacing the spaces in the key with a '_'.  It will return something like this:

| saleID | jsonText |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | '"Handling_Charges": 20' |
| 123 | '"Transportation_Charges": 0' |
| 123 | '"Packing_Charges": 15' |
| 345 | '"Handling_Charges": 0' |
| 345 | '"Transportation_Charges": 10' |
| 345 | '"Packing_Charges": 0' |
| ... | ... |

**The middle query**

This query joins all the strings created by the innermost query to create a new JSON string grouping them by ID:

```
SELECT saleID, CONCAT('{', GROUP_CONCAT(jsonText SEPARATOR ','), '}') AS newJSON
    FROM (
        ... #the innermost query
    ) AS auxTable
    GROUP BY saleID
) AS newJson
```

It returns something like this:

| saleID | newJSON |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | '{"Handling_Charges": 0,"Transportation_Charges": 0,"Packing_Charges": 0}' |
| 345 | '{"Handling_Charges": 0,"Transportation_Charges": 10,"Packing_Charges": 0}' |
| ... | ... |

**The outter query**

And finally, the outter query extracts the JSON data using JSON_EXTRACT and returns the expected output.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Clara. I'm afraid I'm not in a position to change the structure of the data stored in the table.
I could fetch it easily if the data format were like this.

Answer (score 1):

With MySQL 8, you can make use of [JSON_TABLE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html):

```
SELECT mytable.saleID, mytable.amount, hc.amount AS handling_charges,
  tc.amount AS transportation_charges, pc.amount AS packing_charges
FROM mytable 
LEFT JOIN json_table(mytable.extra_charges, 
  '$[*]' COLUMNS(keyname text path '$.key', amount float path '$.amount')
) AS hc ON hc.keyname = 'Handling Charges'
LEFT JOIN json_table(mytable.extra_charges, 
  '$[*]' COLUMNS(keyname text path '$.key', amount float path '$.amount')
) AS tc ON tc.keyname = 'Transportation Charges'
LEFT JOIN json_table(mytable.extra_charges, 
  '$[*]' COLUMNS(keyname text path '$.key', amount float path '$.amount')
) AS pc ON pc.keyname = 'Packing Charges'
```

The part

```
json_table(mytable.extra_charges, 
  '$[*]' COLUMNS(keyname text path '$.key', amount float path '$.amount'))
```

creates, for each row of `mytable`, a derived table with the columns `(keyname, amount)` and a row for each json-key (e.g. in your case up to 3 rows). Out of these rows, we pick, in the `ON`-clause, the row with the correct value (e.g. with `ON pc.keyname = 'Packing Charges'` we select the row with the value 'Packing Charges'), and do this `left join` 3 times for each charge type (to generate the 3 output columns).

Both your data format (json) and the output format (you want a pivot, e.g. what usually would be a row becomes a column) complicates your query, but this is probably a relatively compact solution for your requirements.

Note that you have to modify the query if you e.g. add a new charge type (then you have to add a new output column/left join), which is typical for pivot queries.